# WinForms ActiveX RDP Client Issue With NLA

Tags: c#, activex, rdp

I'm trying to make a WinForms RDP client in C# using the RDP ActiveX control as a bit of a learning exercise. I can get everything working when the target server doesn't use Network Level Authentication (NLA), but when I try and configure the control to use 'EnableCredSspSupport', which I think is needed for NLA, I get the following error when running through the code:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException' occurred in
>   AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll

The code is:

```
        AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting rdp;

        rdp = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();

        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(rdp)).BeginInit();
        rdp.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        rdp.Enabled = true;
        rdp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        rdp.Name = "rdp";
        rdp.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("rdp.OcxState")));
        rdp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(828, 687);
        rdp.TabIndex = 0;

        rdp.AdvancedSettings9.AuthenticationLevel = 2;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;

        MainsplitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(rdp);

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(rdp)).EndInit();

        rdp.Server = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
        rdp.Connect();
```

A lot of this code is mangled together from the following sources, but learning to code is usually standing on the shoulders of giants, right!?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383022(VS.85).aspx
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/3716390/

...And a couple more sources I don't have the reputation to share (First post!)

Any insights out there to help me on my way?

Thanks!

....Aaaand working code:

```
            AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting _RDPClient;
        _RDPClient = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting();

        MainsplitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(_RDPClient);

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(_RDPClient)).BeginInit();
        _RDPClient.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        _RDPClient.Enabled = true;
        _RDPClient.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        _RDPClient.Name = "axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1";
        _RDPClient.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(_RDPClient.OcxState));
        _RDPClient.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(579, 608);
        _RDPClient.TabIndex = 0;
        _RDPClient.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(_RDPClient)).EndInit();

        _RDPClient.OnDisconnected += new IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEventHandler(axMsTscAx_OnDisconnected);


        _RDPClient.Server = IP;
        _RDPClient.Connect();
```

Comment: Setting the AxHost properties early is fine, but you can't touch the properties of the RDP component until it is created.  That happens in typical lazy .NET fashion, at the last possible moment.  Move the assignments to the form's Load event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Soner! I'm brand new at C#, so not quite sure I understand the differences between the AxHost properties and the properties of the RDP component. For a test, I moved everything above to the Form1_Load event handler. I no longer get errors, but I also get no RDP component loaded into the panel.

Comment: The end goal here is to make a simple tabbed RDP client, with tabs for each session. I'd like to have multiple sessions open at the same time. If I move stuff to the _Load event handler, it looks like I wouldn't be able to achieve that? Thanks again!

Comment: The obvious way is to add the tabs later.

Comment: Obvious to someone with expertise, I suppose! Anyway, I've got it working now, and will paste the code above. All I (think I) did was  to move controls.add to the top and started using V8 of the control. I expect this is a bodge that somehow falls in line with your recommendations, but I'm not skilled enough in the dark arts to comment!

Comment: Not sure there's a way to give you any points or anything on this Hans?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I have enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
CType(rdp, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
rdp.CreateControl()
```

Find your equivalent in C#