# Authentication error connecting to Windows 10 via RDP Client in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-desktop

I'm building a C# WinForms application to connect to remote machines on our network.  [Using Microsoft RDP Client Control]

I have the following code:

```
rdpDevice.Server = txtServerName.Text;
rdpDevice.UserName = txtUsername.Text;
IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdpDevice.GetOcx();
secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;
rdpDevice.Connect();
```

The code is working fine for Windows Serer 2008 and Windows 7 Remote PCs.  But when I attempt anything higher than 2008 / Win 7, in this case a Windows 10 PC I get an error.

*"The connection cannot proceed because authentication is not enabled and the remote computer requires that authentication be enabled to connect"*

If i try to remote to the same Windows 10 via MSTSC.exe it is working correctly!  So it only doesn't work using the code above!!

Can anyone give me some direction?
Sorry I'm away from my work machine at present.

Anything i've seen states to modify the SecurityLayer in via RegEdit but I'm not keen to do this as it work via MSTSC.

Comment: Please update your question to say what error you're getting

Comment: Notes updated with error.

Comment: Windows 10 requires network-level authentication by default; you authenticate with the host _before_ establishing the actual RDP connection, as part of the handshake. MSTSC knows how to do this, but the old OCX control doesn't. MSTSC wraps that control and handles the authentication bit before passing things off to it. IIRC, Windows 7 has the ability to do network level authentication, too, but didn't have it turned on by default.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for the reply.  Will do some research now I've a better idea what's happening!  Not sure if this is something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963640/winforms-activex-rdp-client-issue-with-nla

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845555/accessing-remote-desktop/47088855

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following before.Connect() resolved this issue.

```
AdvancedSettings8.EnableCedSspSupport = true
```

Comment: Dude, this totally helped me out! Been searching for so long and this was the ticket to help me connect to a vendor RD Gateway.

Comment: Slight typo in your answer `AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true`

Comment: slightly typo not to be confused ```rdpClient.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true``` base on this answer